# Store Password on windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, passwords, settings, isolatedstorage

Apologies if this has been answered elsewhere, I've had a good look around!
I am developing one windows phone 8 application I want to add privacy to my app. One register page in app where user register with password and security question for forget password. after registration user can login with password from login page. where can I store password and security question in my app and validate them from login page ??? please help me and also how can I create that if user doesn't registered then app will launch register page and if user have registered then  all time application launch the login page?

Comment: Never store a password in Phone's storage in its actual form. Always use encryption.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Window Phone 8 has something called isolated storage? But...

I would not recommend storing the actual password on the phone. Instead you store the hashed password. What you do is when the user types his password, you put it through a hash function. The output is the hash value of the password. This is the value you store on the phone. The cool thing is that it is very difficult to figure out what the original password was, based on the hash value. So when the user is logging in, the password that he types is passed through a the same hashfunction and you compare the output hash value with the one you stored when the user registered. You can even do this with the username as well.

There are plenty of information about hash functions and password security on the internet you can read.

Comment: I cant understand what are you saying. please help me where can i store and retrieve password in my app.

Comment: You store it like any other variable, in a file, in the settings or whatever. But you hash it first. There is a simple explanation of it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYfMZx2hy_8

Comment: Thanks.
I had done with the help of this link.http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh487164(v=vs.105).aspx
i want to know code for change password and code for validate that password to login.


what is the code for  if user had already registered then open login page when app will launch and else open register page when app will be launch?? Please help me.

Comment: I don't undertand what you mean? Can you be more specific/detailed about what your problem is?

Comment: I had created Program for Storing password using isolated storage. now next step is when user launch my app then app should be check if user already registered then app will launch login page of my app else it will launch register page which is located in my app. how it possible please help me.
 my app does not require any type internet connection. 
simply i am creating simple photo locker application on windows phone 8. send me link if any  sample like photo locker app available. please help me